# How do I get image/file data on postman using get method?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js, postman, multer

I have implemented a post method for file uploadation and now I want implement get() to check that either I'm getting right response of image using postman and without using UI.
Here is my code of POST method.

```
// route controller for Profile Uploadation
exports.uploadFiles = async (req, res) => {
    try{
        console.log('Call from upload files',req.file);
        if(req.file == undefined ){
            return res.status(500).send({message:'You must have to select a file'});
        }

        //console.log('req of id',req.params.id);
        const profileUsername = req.session.Auth;
        Profile.create({
            type:req.body.mimetype,
            name:req.file.originalname,
            post_username:profileUsername,
            data:fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/../uploads/" + req.file.filename),
        }).then(image=>{
            fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + "/../uploads/" + image.name, image.data);
            req.session.profile_img_id = image.id;
            console.log('req of image id',image.id);

            return res.status(201).send({message:'Image file has been uploaded successfully'});
        });
    } catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        return res.send(`Error when trying upload images: ${error}`);
    }
}
```

**And Controller for file**

```
const multer=require('multer');

const imageFilter=(req,file,cb)=>{
    if(file.mimetype.startsWith("image")){
        cb(null,true);
    } else {
        cb('Please upload only images.', false)
    }
};

var storage=multer.diskStorage({
    destination:(req,file,cb)=>{
        cb(null,__dirname + "/../uploads/" );
    },
    filename:(req,file,cb)=>{
        cb(null, `${Date.now()}-usama-${file.originalname}`);
    }
})

var uploadFile=multer({ storage : storage, fileFilter : imageFilter });
module.exports=uploadFile;
```

And the route file is

```
  router.post('/upload_profile', posts.sessionForApi, uploads.single('file'), posts.uploadFiles);
```

The issue I'm facing is not know how to implelment get() in to fetch image data and to test that response on postman.

Comment: Did you get the solution.? I also have the same issue I want to retrieve image in Postman..

Comment: @ShehryarTanoli 
 Did you find the answer?

Comment: @sirj I have tested this on my browser and works fine....Hit the Url in your browser of the image which is stored in your file.

Comment: @ShehryarTanoli thanks! it was a while ago so i dont really remember the solution, but i think if you use prettify in postman, it shoudl show