# How do I get an image to postman using Express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman

I have some jpeg and png photos in my local machine. How do i show them on my postman using express.js?

Do I use sendFile?

And is it possible to print more than one photo?

Here is a template

```
app = require("express")();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {

res.send("I want to send the image here")

})
```

Same Question as [How do I get image/file data on postman using get method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63685767/how-do-i-get-image-file-data-on-postman-using-get-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to do this is to serve the files statically by using [express static middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).

Assuming your images reside in a `uploads` folder in your app's root, you'd simply add to your express app:

```
app.use("/uploads", express.static('uploads'))
```

You can then request it through postman/browser with `GET http://your-host/uploads/name-of-image.png`.

Comment: thank you for your answer :) i was new so i didnt know that i had to checkmark it